# Mixins with Flow type annotations

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, flowtype

I'm using ES6 and the [Flow](http://flowtype.org/) type checker in a project.

Suppose I've got two [type aliases](http://flowtype.org/docs/type-aliases.html#_), defined only in terms of what methods are expected of them (like a Java interface):

```
type Airplane = {
    takeOff: (() => void);
    land: (() => void);
};

type Car = {
    drive: ((speed: number) => void);
};
```

How would I define a class `FlyingCar` to demonstrate to the type checker that it is both a `Car` and an `Airplane`? I'm using ECMAScript 6 classes.

For a type I suspect it would look something like:

```
type FlyingCar = (Airplane & Car);
```

I can't seem to reconcile what I want with [the class syntax](http://flowtype.org/docs/classes.html#_), though, since it seems to be tied into ES6's class syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to demonstrate it to flow. Flow implements structural type system, so you simply need to implement both type in your class.

This doesn't type check:

```
class FlyingCar {}

function flyInACar(car: Airplane & Car): void {

}

flyInACar(new FlyingCar());
```

this does:

```
class FlyingCar {
  takeOff(): void {}
  land(): void {}
  drive(speed: number): void {}
}


function flyInACar(car: Airplane & Car): void {

}

flyInACar(new FlyingCar());
```